# How to redirect domain with the same query string using .htaccess in Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect domain with the same path (query string) to another domain. In frontend we are using **Angular** app and backend is **Laravel**. I have tried with the **.htaccess** below but it doesn't use the path. **It just redirects to index.php page**.

- I want this: xxx.com/this-is/the-path -> yyy.com/this-is/the-path
- But I get this: xxx.com/this-is/the-path -> yyy.com/index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

# -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
# If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# --

# CustomRedirect start
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.io$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yyy.lt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.lt/$1 [L,QSA,R=302]
# CustomRedirect end

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why you need to that ? the frontend should be calling the correct domain in the first place.

Comment: @Lk77 we have several domains pointing to the same server and want to assign one default domain and other domains should be redirected to the default one. and all domains using the same .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # CustomRedirect start
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.io$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yyy.lt$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.lt/$1 [L,QSA,R=302]
> # CustomRedirect end
> ```

You've put this redirect rule in the wrong place. This needs to go at the top of the file. You've placed it after the internal rewrite to `index.php` (the Laravel front-controller), so it naturally ends up redirecting to `index.php`, not the URL-path you are requesting.

(It would only redirect as intended if you requested a physical file or directory at one of the other domains, since the request would not be rewritten to `index.php` in this case.)

The `QSA` flag is also superfluous here. The query string is appended by default.

---

*Aside:*

> with the same path (query string)

The "path" part of the URL is not the "query string". Your examples contain a URL-path only, there is no "query string" in the examples you've posted. The query string is the part of the URL following the first `?` (question mark). However, the above rule will preserve both the URL-path and the query string (if any).

> ```
> # Handle Authorization Header
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
> ```

This rule is also in the wrong place. This needs to go *before* the `# Handle Front Controller...` rule, not after it. Currently, this rule is not doing anything (maybe you don't need it).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
>
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
> ```

Likewise, this rule block (at the end of the file) is also not doing anything. The request will be rewritten to `index.php` (the Laravel front-controller) first. (You cannot do both.)

Comment: Thank you! Moving the rule to the top worked... and also thank you for other explanations.